# Stopwatch. Counting seconds. javafx

Tags: java, javafx, stopwatch

I want to make a stopwatch (hours:minutes:seconds), and I thought I should do it in the following way. Variable result will be passed into my `TextField`, `startTime` will be time at which we started the stopwatch, and passed time will be current time (const.)

```
result=startTime-elapsedTime;
```

But I don't know which date class to use and also I don't know how to repeat this.

`result=startTime-elapsedTime;` every second in order to update TextField.

all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Since you're just asking for suggestions it looks to me as too broad. You should edit your question with a specific problem and at that point we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TimeLine` animation to update your `TextField`:

```
 public void startTimer() {
        timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0),
                e ->advanceDuration()),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1)));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

  private void advanceDuration() {
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds++;
        } else {
            seconds = 0;
            if (minutes < 59) {
                minutes++;    
            }else{
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

According to the comments, here is a solution using an `AnimationTimer`:

```
public class Timer extends Application {

    private AnimationTimer timer;
    private Label          lblTime = new Label("0 .s");
    private int            seconds;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        private long lastTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (lastTime != 0) {
                if (now > lastTime + 1_000_000_000) {
                    seconds++;
                    lblTime.setText(Integer.toString(seconds) + " .s");
                    lastTime = now;
                }
            } else {
                lastTime = now;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() {
            super.stop();
            lastTime = 0;
            seconds = 0;
        }
    };

    Button btnStart = new Button("START");
    btnStart.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        lblTime.setText("0 .s");
        timer.start();
    });

    Button btnStop = new Button("STOP");
    btnStop.setOnAction(e -> timer.stop());


        VBox box = new VBox(16, lblTime, btnStart, btnPause);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(box)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mipa My understanding, though I admit I haven't checked this, is that under the hood this works essentially the same way as the `AnimationTimer`; i.e. on each pulse, for each running animation, the current frame time in the animation is computed and the state of the animation is updated. Thus any small errors would not accumulate. Again, though, I haven't checked and I agree that an `AnimationTimer` is a better fit here.

Comment: I just thought that it is not a good idea to rely on unproven assumptions about the stability and correctnes of a timeline, which is not really made for this purpose, if the same can be achieved in a much more straight forward and predictable way with an AnimationTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AnimationTimer class. You have to provide a method which is then called automatically at roughly 60 Hz. There you can do your calculation and update of the GUI.